# Проблемы с PyAudio

Tags: python, windows-10, библиотеки, установка, pyaudio

Всем привет.
Решил написать небольшую программу для распознавания голосовых команд на Python.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
import pyttsx3

speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()

def talk(words):
     print(words)
     speak_engine.say(words)
     speak_engine.runAndWait()
     speak_engine.stop()

talk("go talk")

def command():
     r=sr.Recognizer()

     with sr.Microphone() as sourse:
          print("Talk")
          r.pauses_threshold=1
          r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=1)
          audio=r.listen(sourse)

     try:
          assigment=r.recognize_google(audio).lover
          print("you're sayed:"+assigment)
     except sr.UnknownValueError:
          talk("I'm not understend you")
          assigment=command()

     return(assigment)

def makeSomething(assigment):
     if'open you tube' in assigment:
          talk("in process")
          url='https://www.youtube.com/'
          webbrowser.open(url)
     elif 'stop' in assigment:
          talk("done")
          sys.exit()

while True:
     makeSomething(command())
```

выдает проблему

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ИМЯ\PycharmProjects\voice\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ИМЯ/PycharmProjects/voice/venv/Include/voice_recognition.py", line 45, in <module>
    makeSomething(command())
  File "C:/Users/ИМЯ/PycharmProjects/voice/venv/Include/voice_recognition.py", line 20, in command
    with sr.Microphone() as sourse:
  File "C:\Users\ИМЯ\PycharmProjects\voice\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "C:\Users\ИМЯ\PycharmProjects\voice\venv\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Process finished with exit code 1"
```

Хотя `go talk` произносит. как смог понять, проблема с PyAudio.
Хоть она и установлена. Прилагаю скрин[image: скрин]
Из командной строки. подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему или может посоветуйте другую библиотеку, чтобы код работал.
Кстати, путем установки через скопированную с pip ссылка не работала и пришлось использовать сторонние [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)

Comment: В командной строке выполните команду python --version

Comment: И покажите результат

Comment: @Александр, Python 3.8.7

Comment: Хорошо, теперь выполните команду python

Comment: далее import pyaudio

Comment: @Александр, сделал, но,увы, то же самое выдает. хотя импорт прошел:                                            
                                        Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1697]
(c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2018. Все права защищены.

C:\Users\ИМЯ>python
Python 3.8.7 (tags/v3.8.7:6503f05, Dec 21 2020, 17:59:51) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyaudio
>>>

Comment: Тогда запустите свой скрипт из командной строки

Comment: python myscript.py

Comment: @Александр,C:\Users\ИМЯ>python voice_recognition.py

python: can't open file 'voice_recognition.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Вам запустить командную строку в папке со скриптом

Comment: @Александр, пришлось заново загрузить несколько библиотек. теперь, как я понял, ругается на сам код: C:\Users\ИМЯ\PycharmProjects\voice\venv\Include>python voice_recognition.py
go talk
Talk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "voice_recognition.py", line 45, in <module>
    makeSomething(command())
  File "voice_recognition.py", line 23, in command
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=1)
NameError: name 'source' is not defined

Comment: voice_recognition.py это название вашего скрипта?

Comment: @Александр, да, оно

Comment: Если хотите по TeamViewer помогу, так непонятно что вы там делаете.

Comment: @Александр,да, буду очень благодарен. как на счет завтра? когда вам удобно?

Comment: WhatsApp  или Telegram есть?

Comment: Что бы списываться